# Should I assign all my back end processing to a worker role?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-worker-roles

Fairly new to Azure and the whole worker role concept, previously if I wanted some back end work done I would just create a windows forms application and have it as a scheduled task.

With my new site I have created a windows form application which I have running every hour which reads in XML feeds and does all the processing an inserts the information into sql azure.

There is also image links that I want to store in azure blob storage and possibly resize them , which I had trouble doing from my vb.net application.

My question is should I move all the processing from my windows form application to the worker role or should I set up a worker role to just process the image to blob storage?

How much compute time does a worker role use? I have seen examples of where there is a sleep timer but is it possible to run it every hour on the hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily set up a timer to trigger every hour on the hour. Where you run your code this depends on your application architecture. If you have a web role, you can place this in your web role instead of a dedicated worker role unless you really need the extra processing power of a separate instance and are willing to pay for it. Also, the number of instances of each role (web/worker) will add complications to the solution.

A detailed outline of your architecture would provide a better frame of reference for the answer you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Worker role is designed for doing all sort of background activities. so you can move all of processing logic from windows application to workerrole. It is simply a class library with an entry point class.

You can not schedule any work automatically in worker role. You will have to right a logic for your self. worker role is executing a piece of code in an infinite loop. You will be charged for the no. of hours you have used in worker role (compute), it does not matter your worker role is idle or processing something. plus if you are using blob and queue, you will also be charged for accessing them and for storing data in them.

Comment: Because I have 2 web instances will this mean if I make a worker role there will be 2 worker role instances? is there a way to set the amount of worker role instances?

Comment: It is not neccessary to match up worker role instances with your web intances. You can specify no. of instances in service configuration file, this file is then consumed by windows azure to spin up required no. of web or worker roles.